# How to reference URL content in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have link below it work fine but i just want to use Url.Content please advise, thank you

```
 $('#btnAddConsumer').click(function () {
        window.open('/ProductDetails/AddNewProduct/', 'AddProduct', 'height=' + (window.screen.height - 470) + ',width=820,left=' + (window.screen.width - 5) + ',top=10,status=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need the UrlHelper's Action method:

```
'#btnAddConsumer').click(function () {
        window.open('@Url.Action("AddNewProduct", "ProductDetails")', 'AddProduct', 'height=' + (window.screen.height - 470) + ',width=820,left=' + (window.screen.width - 5) + ',top=10,status=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
$('#btnAddConsumer').click(function () {
        window.open('@Url.Content("~/ProductDetails/AddNewProduct/")', 'AddProduct', 'height=' + (window.screen.height - 470) + ',width=820,left=' + (window.screen.width - 5) + ',top=10,status=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');
    });
```